# How to hook an unknown number of functions - x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86, hook

**Problem description**

At runtime, I am given a list of addresses of functions (in the same process). Each time any of them is called, I need to log its address.

**My attempt**

If there was just one function (with help of a hooking library like [subhook](https://github.com/Zeex/subhook)) I could create a hook:

```
create_hook(function_to_be_hooked, intermediate)

intermediate(args...):
  log("function with address {&function_to_be_hooked} got called")
  remove_hook(function_to_be_hooked)
  ret = function_to_be_hooked(args...)
  create_hook(function_to_be_hooked, intermediate)
  return ret
```

This approach does not trivially extend. I could add any number of functions at compile-time, but I only know how many I need at runtime. If I hook multiple functions with the same `intermediate`, it doesn't know who called it.

**Details**

It seems like this problem should be solved by a hooking library. I am using C/C++ and Linux and the only options seem to be [subhook](https://github.com/Zeex/subhook) and [funchook](https://github.com/kubo/funchook), but none of them seem to support this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

This should be fairly doable with assembly language manually, like if you were modifying a hook library.  The machine code that overwrites the start of the original function can set a register or global variable before jumping to (or `call`ing) the hook.  Using `call` would push a unique return address which the hook likely wouldn't want to actually return to. (So it unbalances the return-address predictor stack, unless the hook uses `ret` with a modified return address, or it uses some prefixes as padding to make the `call hook` or `call [rel hook_ptr]` or whatever end at an instruction boundary of the original code so it can `ret`.)

Like `mov al, imm8` if the function isn't variadic in the x86-64 System V calling convention, or `mov r11b, imm8` in x86-64.  Or `mov ah, imm8` would work in x86-64 SysV without disturbing the AL= # of XMM args for a variadic function and still only be 2 bytes.  Or use `push imm8`.

If the hook function itself was written in asm, it would be straightforward for it to look for a register, and extra stack arg, or just a return address from a `call`, as an extra arg without disturbing its ability to find the args for the hooked function.  If it's written in C, looking in a global (or thread-local) variable avoids needing a custom calling convention.

---

#### But with existing hook libraries, assuming you're right they don't pass an `int id`

Using that library interface, it seems you'd need to generate an unknown number of unique things that are callable as a function pointer?  That's not something ISO C can do.  It can be strictly ahead-of-time compiled, not needing to generate any new machine code at run-time. It's compatible with a strict Harvard architecture.

You could define a huge array of function pointers to `hook1()`, `hook2()`, etc. which each look for their own piece of side data in another struct member of that array.  Enough hook functions that however many you need at run-time, you'll already have enough.  Each one can hard-code the array element it should access for its unique string.

You could use some C preprocessor macros to define some large more-than-enough number of hooks, and separately get an array initialized with structs containing function pointers to them.  Some CPP tricks may allow iterating over names so you don't have to manually write out `define_hook(0)` `define_hook(1)` ... `define_hook(MAX_HOOKS-1)`.  Or maybe have a counter as a CPP macro that gets `#defined` to a new higher value.

Unused hooks would be sitting in memory and in your executable on disk, but wouldn't ever be called so they wouldn't be hot in cache.  Ones that didn't share a page with any other code wouldn't ever need to get paged in to RAM at all.  Same for later parts of the array of pointers and side-data.  It's inelegant and clunky, and doesn't allow an unbounded number, but if you can reasonably say that 1024 or 8000 "should be enough for everyone", then this can work.

---

Another way also has many downsides, different but worse than the above.  Especially that it requires calling the rest of your program from the bottom of a recursion (*not* just calling an init function that returns normally), and uses a lot of stack space.  (You might `ulimit -s` to bump up your stack size limit over Linux's usual 8MiB.)  Also it requires GNU extensions.

[GNU C nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) can make new callable entities with, making "trampoline" machine code on the stack when you take the address of a nested function.  This would your stack executable, so there's a security hardening downside.  There'd be one copy of the actual machine code for the nested function, but `n` copies of trampoline code that sets up a pointer to the right stack frame.  And `n` instances of a local variable that you can arrange to have different values.

So you could use a recursive function that went through your array of hooks like `foo(counter+1, hooks+1)`, and have the hook be a nested function that reads `counter`.  Or instead of a counter, it can be a `char*` or whatever you like; you just set it in this invocation of the function.

This is pretty nasty (the hook machine code and data is all on the stack) and uses potentially a lot of stack space for the rest of your program.  **You can't return from this recursion or your hooks will break.**  So the recursion base-case will have to be (tail) calling a function that implements the rest of your program, **not returning to your ultimate caller until the program is ending.**

---

C++ has some `std::` callable objects, like `std::function = std::bind` of a member function of a specific object, but they're not type-compatible with function pointers.

You can't pass a `std::function *` pointer to a function expecting a bare `void (*fptr)(void)` function pointer; making that happen would potentially require the library to allocate some executable memory and generate machine code in it.  **But ISO C++ is designed to be strictly ahead-of-time compilable**, so they don't support that.

`std::function<void(void)> f = std::bind(&Class::member, hooks[i]);` compiles, but the resulting `std::function<void(void)>` object can't convert to a `void (*)()` function pointer.  (https://godbolt.org/z/TnYM6MYTP).  The caller needs to know it's invoking a `std::function<void()>` object, not a function pointer.  There is no new machine code, just data, when you do this.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive answer! I implemented a version of (2) using C++ non-type template parameters. However at a scale of tens of thousands of functions, compilation takes a few minutes which is too much for my use-case.

Comment: Putting this function generation in separate translation unit solves compilation time overhead issues, but still leaves a bloated binary. Interestingly it also segfaults clangd.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is to follow a debugger path.

You would need

- a `uin8_t *` -> `uint8_t` map,
- a trap handler, and
- a single step handler

In broad stokes,

- When you get a request to monitor a function, add its address, and the byte pointed by it to the map. Patch the pointed-to byte with `int3`.
- The trap handler shall get an offending address from the exception frame, and log it. Then It shall unpatch the byte with the value from the map, set the single-step flag (TF) in FLAGS (again, in the exception frame), and return. That will execute the instruction, and raise a single-step exception.

  You *can* set TF from user-space yourself and catch the resulting `SIGTRAP`s until you clear it (on a POSIX OS); it's more common for TF to only be used by debuggers, e.g. set by the kernel as part of Linux's `ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP)`.  But setting/clearing TF is not a privileged operation.  (Patching bytes of machine code with `int3` is how debuggers implement software breakpoints, not using x86's `dr0-7` hardware debug registers.  In your own process, no system call is necessary after an `mprotect` to make it writeable.)
- The single-step handler shall re-patch `int3`, and return to let the program run until it hits `int3` again.

In POSIX, the exception frame is pointed by `uap` argument to a `sigaction` handler.

**PROS:**

- No bloated binary
- No compile-time instrumentation

**CONS:**

- Tricky to implement correctly. Remapping text segment writable; invalidating I-cache; perhaps something more.
- Huge performance penalty; a no-go in real-time system.

Comment: I think your "PSW" is short for Processor or Program Status Word.  That's not x86 terminology; on x86, the register you're talking about (which includes TF, the single-step trap flag) is FLAGS, the bottom 16 bits of EFLAGS / RFLAGS.  It seems PSW is a register name on IBM S/360 etc., and maybe others but [the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_status_word) is about S/360.

Comment: @PeterCordes PSW I referred to comes from an ancient 68k (aka cpu32) Motorola architecture. In any case we all new where the single step flag is.

Comment: The fact that an x86 expert familiar with multiple other architectures was able to know what you actually meant, doesn't mean all readers will!  If you're writing an x86 answer, it's much better to use x86 terminology, especially after someone reminds you what the correct term is; not taking time to check while writing the answer initially is understandable.

Comment: @PeterCordes _it's much better to use x86 terminology_ - Agreed. However, I expect that someone undertaking such project shall not be entirely illiterate.

Answer (score 0):

[Funchook](https://github.com/kubo/funchook) now implements this functionality (on master branch, to be released with 2.0.0).